# IOS NSXMLParser Not getting all the text from the element?

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, xml-parsing

I am using NSXMLParser to parse an XML file, it parses the long description of some elements but on some it just skips most of the text and grabs only some text from the end.

```
<communities>

<community>
        <name>Newport Bay Club</name>
        <primaryImageURL>http://bocaratonrealestatemarket.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/newprtbay200px.jpg</primaryImageURL>
        <thedescription>Newport Bay Club is one of the most desirable communities in Boca Raton. This beautiful community is in a perfect location on Jog Road north of Clint Moore Road. Newport Bay Club is man-gated 24 hours. Developed between 1988 and 1995, it features finely detailed single family homes that are separated into four subdivisions and surrounded by several serene lakes. Residences range in size from 1,500 to over 3,500 square feet and are offered in a variety of styles. Newport Bay Club residents enjoy amenities such as lighted tennis courts, an Olympic size pool, large clubhouse with meeting rooms for private and community functions, state of the art fitness center with aerobics studio and locker rooms, indoor racquetball courts, basketball courts, library, and a playground for children.</thedescription>
    </community>
<community>
        <name>Boca Country Club</name>
        <primaryImageURL>http://bocaratonrealestatemarket.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/bocacountryclub200px.jpg</primaryImageURL>
        <thedescription>Just minutes away from beaches, restaurants, shopping, and parks, Boca Country Club is a perfect location for families and professionals. Its 945 single family homes, townhomes, condos and villas are divided into 12 subdivisions and secured by a 24 hour manned gate. Boca Country Club is in an A-Rated public school district, though some residents choose to send their children to one of the local private schools. Tennis and golf membership is available, but it is not required to live in the Boca Country Club community.  </thedescription>
    </community>    
    <community>
        <name>Woodfield Country Club</name>
        <primaryImageURL>http://bocaratonrealestatemarket.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/WoodfieldCountryClub200px.jpg</primaryImageURL>
        <thedescription>Woodfield Country Club, located in the heart of Boca Raton, is a wonderful private gated community. A championship golf course and tranquil lakes separate the quaint sub communities.  Once past the gate, Woodfield’s private back streets are lined with lush tropical landscaping. In the center of the country club’s beautiful grounds lies its exceptional clubhouse. This is where friends and neighbors get together to enjoy one of the 5 individual restaurants, Cascades Spa and Fitness Center, inviting swimming pool, or Youth Activities Center. Woodfield Country Club has an activity for everyone. </thedescription>
    </community>    
</communities>
```

In this XML it gets the full `thedescription` tag from the first two communities but not Woodfield Country Club? Even if I move that community to the middle or beginning of the XML file.

My parser code:

```
-(id) loadXMLByURL:(NSString *)urlString
{
    _communities            = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSURL *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData  *data   = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    parser          = [[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithData:data];
    parser.delegate = self;
    [parser parse];
    return self;
}

    - (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
{

    if(!currentNodeContent)
        currentNodeContent = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithString:string];
    else
        [currentNodeContent appendString:string];
}

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"community"])
    {
        currentCommunity = [Community alloc];

    }
    }

- (void) parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementname namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName
{
            if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"name"])
        {
            NSString *trimmed = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

            currentCommunity.name = trimmed;
            currentNodeContent = nil;
        }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"primaryImageURL"])
    {
        NSString *trimmed = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

        currentCommunity.imageURL = trimmed;
        NSLog(@"%@ ", trimmed);

        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }

        if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"thedescription"])
        {
            NSString *trimmed = [currentNodeContent stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceCharacterSet]];

            currentCommunity.commDescription = trimmed;
            currentNodeContent = nil;

    }
    if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"community"])
    {
        [self.communities addObject:currentCommunity];

        currentCommunity = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}
```

I don't know why it will work for some community descriptions and not other? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

The XML file URL: http://steveedwin.com/test2.xml

Comment: @maddy This did not work it just appended all of the nodes into one string?

Comment: You need to reset the mutable string for each element.

Comment: @maddy Can you please help me understand I don't understand, I'm still learning. How do I reset it? Please and thank you.

Comment: Look at the question I referenced. Notice how the OP resets the mutable string to `nil` after finding the element. You need to do that in addition to the changes posted in the answer.

Comment: I do reset mine to `nil` like so
 `if ([elementname isEqualToString:@"community"])
    {
        [self.communities addObject:currentCommunity];
        NSLog(@"%@ ", currentCommunity.commDescription);

        currentCommunity = nil;
        currentNodeContent = nil;
    }
}`

Comment: It needs to be reset more often. If you only want the text for the "Community" tag, reset `currentNodeContent` when you find the start element for "Community".

Comment: @maddy Edited Post with updated code;
Okay now it separates the nodes but adds spaces before the node text, how do I remove the spaces, I have a url and cannot have the spaces.

Comment: Do a little searching on how to trim whitespace from a string.

Comment: @maddy Edited code with trimming and the white space is still there, I swear I am trying everything.

Comment: Use `whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet`.